# Cannot access to any port of Azure VM except RD (3389) even when inbound rules are defined

Tags: firewall, azure, port

I have HTTP port 80 opened in Windows firewall and also configured inbound rules of NSG to allow port 80. Still I can't telnet port 80. Only RDP port 3389 works..

Any help is appreciated... Thanks a lot..

[NSG inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVFX0.png)
[Windows Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUzKe.png)

Comment: please run this command in your windows VM `netstat -ant | findstr 80`, make sure your http was running.

Comment: Please offer your windows firewall settings about port 80 screenshot.

Comment: Can you browse it in your Azure VM? use IE to browse it with private IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, add port 80 to NSG inbound rules and open port in windows firewall inbound rules (for test we can turn off VM's windows firewall), we will access website from outside.
In your scenario, maybe we should check web site work on IPv4 or IPv6 or both? We can use this command to check it:

```
C:\Users\jason>netstat -ant
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           Offload State

  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:3389              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
```

We can find web service listen on port 80 and work on IPv4 and IPv6, so we can use IPv4(public IP address) and port 80 to access this web site.

We should make sure web service work on IPv4.

By the way, we should check your  **Vnet**-->**subnet**, does this subnet associated with a **NSG**, if yes, we should modify this NSG's inbound rules, add port 80 to this NSG.

Comment: There's no good or valid reason to turn off Windows Firewall.

Comment: @joeqwerty your are right, I will update it, thanks.